# How to compress and shrink the size of a text-only hand crafted PDF file?

Tags: pdf

I have created a PDF file (837 bytes) as a template for load testing an application:

```
%PDF-1.1
%µ¶

1 0 obj
<</Type/Catalog/Pages 2 0 R>>
endobj

2 0 obj
<</Type/Pages/Kids[3 0 R]/Count 1/MediaBox[0 0 595 841]>>
endobj

3 0 obj
<</Type/Page/Parent 2 0 R/Resources<</Font<</F1<</Type/Font/Subtype/Type1/BaseFont/Times-Roman>>>>>>/Contents 4 0 R>>
endobj

4 0 obj
<</Length 356>>
stream
BT
/F1 18 Tf
10 803 Td
(${title}) Tj
ET

BT
/F1 14 Tf
10 773 Td
(Type: ${type}) Tj
ET

BT
/F1 14 Tf
10 753 Td
(Date: ${date}) Tj
ET

BT
/F1 14 Tf
10 733 Td
(Name: ${name}) Tj
ET

BT
/F1 40 Tf
10 440.5 Td
(This is a dummy statement) Tj
0 -50 Td
(for testing purposes generated) Tj
0 -50 Td
(for load testing.) Tj
ET

BT
/F1 14 Tf
10 14 Td
(Page 1/1) Tj
ET


endstream
endobj

xref
0 5
0000000000 65536 f 
0000000016 00000 n 
0000000062 00000 n 
0000000136 00000 n 
0000000270 00000 n 

trailer
<</Size 5/Root 1 0 R>>
startxref
676
%%EOF
```

I replace `${title}`, `${type}`, etc. placeholders to produce dummy PDF files for testing purposes.

Is there a way to compress and shrink the size of the generated PDF file further (PDF version does not have to be 1.1 -- it can be the latest version of the PDF standard).

Is there a way to combine the following objects into one, eliminating the multiple BT/ET words and font declarations (`/F1 14 Tf`):

```
BT
/F1 18 Tf
10 803 Td
(${title}) Tj
ET

BT
/F1 14 Tf
10 773 Td
(Type: ${type}) Tj
ET

BT
/F1 14 Tf
10 753 Td
(Statement Date: ${date}) Tj
ET

BT
/F1 14 Tf
10 733 Td
(Name: ${name}) Tj
ET

BT
/F1 40 Tf
10 440.5 Td
(This is a dummy statement) Tj
0 -50 Td
(for testing purposes generated) Tj
0 -50 Td
(for load testing.) Tj
ET

BT
/F1 14 Tf
10 14 Td
(Page 1/1) Tj
ET
```

?

Ideally I am looking to shrink its size down to 420 bytes or less.

Comment: I'm not sure how to get it smaller but keep in mind that you might make it a synthetic load test, one which isn't related to the real world load the application might experience, by doing so.

Comment: You can compress the streams e.g. using `mutool` from `mupdf`. Ideally this should also compress the repeated parts in the stream, but you'd have to try to see how good the compression is.

Comment: I had already tried that but it increases the file size. Is there a tool to keep the file format PDF, but zip/gzip permissible sections of the file?

Comment: Yes, you can merge all the BT/ET into one. And you can compress the content stream, Flate/zlib would be good. No idea how compression got you a larger file. It is also possible to group some of your indirect objects into a single compressed object stream.